# using Max() in Orderby

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have this line which runs till I enabled  RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning.

Here let's say what I want to do is to sort the results (customers) based on their latest order date.

```
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.orders.Max(y=>y.CreateDate))
```

After I configure the context as follow I realised the Max() is not converted to TSql.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warning =>
    {
        warning.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning);
    });
}
```

The error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'Max()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

I assume calculating the max locally is against having a better performance. Is there any way to calculate the max on SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call aggregate methods (Average, Min, Max) in a LINQ query using a non-nullable type, it has no choice but to evaluate it locally.

To avoid this, cast your Max value to a nullable type and it will be evaluated in the database.

Assuming CreateDate is of type DateTime, casting it to DateTime? (nullable) should work.

Here's what your query should look like:

```
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.orders.Max(y=> (DateTime?)y.CreateDate))
```

[This answer referenced from official Github Repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11797)

Comment: Thank you
Excellent. That solved my 2 issues (out of 3) but I have another one which seems tricky.
In that one I have something like this:
.Max(c=>c.Orders.Max(o=>o.date))
Tried the casting didn't work.

Thought?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more context for me to help with that query. What does your DbContext look like? What is the intent of your query? The query you have posted here cannot be evaluated in the database as your outer Max is looking at the C# object rather than a database column.

Comment: right.
Let's say I have companies which have customers which have orders.
In one query I want to set the order in a way that brings the "companies with latest orders first". (Hope this is clear enough). 
This query is a search.
So I have lie like this:
.OrderByDescending(x =>x.Customers.Max(y => y.Orders.Any() ? y.Orders.Max(z => z.DateCreatedUtc) : DateTime.MinValue))
so if a company has no order consider the recent order date as DAteTime.MinValue.

Comment: Thanks to @ivan-stoev:
x.Customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders).Max(o => (DateTime?) o.DateCreatedUtc)
Worked.

Answer (score 6):

If you have EF Core [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) enabled, you would see the following warning:

> => Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor
>
> Possible unintended use of a potentially throwing aggregate method (Min, Max, Average) in a subquery. Client evaluation will be used and operator will throw if
>    no data exists. Changing the subquery result type to a nullable type will allow full translation.

Basically they are trying to preserve the throwing behavior of the aforementioned aggregate methods in LINQ to Objects.

And the solution is in the last sentence. e.g. if the type of `CreateDate` is `DateTime`, then

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.orders.Max(y => (DateTime?)y.CreateDate))
```

will be translated to SQL.